# How to find the first instance of a min and max value in a file using python?

Tags: python

I am using a file that has numerous lines of data in the following format:

```
Niger                                              WB_LI   37 Africa                    2000
```

The first column is the country name, the second is income level, the third is percentage of people vaccinated, the fifth is the year. I am trying to find out the max. and min percentages given a year and income level by the user. I am also trying to find the line where these two values occur for the first time in the file. The code that I have written so far gives me the correct min and max values, but not the lines where they occur for the first time. For example, if there are a bunch of zeroes, I should be able to print out the first country with the first 0%, not the last country with the 0%. My codes are:

```
#looping through each line
for line in input_file:
            #checking for user input(income level and year) in each line
            if 'WB_LI' in line and year in line:
                #printing lines that matches user input
                print(line)
                total+=int(line[58:61])
                count_instance+=1
                if int(line[58:61])>int(max_value):
                       max_value=(line[58:61])
                if max_value in line:
                    max_line=line
                if int(line[58:61])<int(min_value):
                    min_value=(line[58:61])
                if min_value in line:
                    min_line=line
```

I would really appreciate if someone could give me some suggestion to fix my code. Thanks.

NOTE: I am not allowed to use list, dictionary, or tuple. All I have is a file and I can open or close or read and write a file.

Comment: I think it's quite offensive to African people.

Comment: @Marian http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were nearly there; instead of storing a line when the maximum or minimum value is found in that line, store the line when you find a new maximum or minimum value, in the same `if` statement:

```
for line in input_file:
    if 'WB_LI' in line and year in line:
        #printing lines that matches user input
        percentage = int(line[58:61])
        total += percentage
        count_instance+=1
        if percentage > max_value:
            max_value = percentage
            max_line = line
        if percentage < min_value:
            min_value = percentage
            min_line = line
```

For convenience this code parses out the percentage just *once* for each line.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. I tried your code and it is indeed giving the right answer. Appreciate your help.